# Batch file execution from java return null as result

Tags: java, batch-file, return-value, execution

I have a bat file to get executed from java and save the output result in java variable. The script run fine when run from cmd and gets executed from java as well and i do get exit value in java but unable to get return echo value. Below is the java code that i am using and the bat script as well.

**Java Code**

```
String filePath = "1234";
StringBuilder scriptOutputResult = new StringBuilder();
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe", "/c", "start C:\\Thread\\Value\\xyz.bat", filePath});
exitCode = process.waitFor();
log.info("Command returned exit code = {}", exitCode);
try (BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()))) {
    log.info("Reading the output of shell script");
    String line = null;
    while ((line = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
        scriptOutputResult.append(line).append("\n");
         }
     log.info("Output from the script executed is :{}", scriptOutputResult.toString());
}
```

**Output.log**

```
Command returned exit code = 0
Output from the script executed is :
```

**xyz.bat**

```
@ECHO OFF
SET filePath=%1
ECHO %filePath%

IF "%filePath%" == "" (
    ECHO Missing File Path
    EXIT /B 1
    GOTO :eof
    ) ELSE (
    ECHO %filePath%
    EXIT /B 0
    GOTO :eof
)
```

Please let me know if i am missing something in batch file or any other way to get the output of the file in java in some other way.

Comment: What's the point of using `start` to run the batch file? `start` without `/WAIT` does, well, not wait for the script to finish, so you will never be able to capture its exit code…

Comment: Correct, if i remove the start from the above array it works and return the echo value as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the process stdout while it is running, not afterwards.
So instead of

```
exitcode = process.waitFor()
```

you need to check if the process has terminated. If not, read all data from it's stdout and stderr streams. This loop will keep you pretty busy.

Once the process has terminated you have the exit code and the output of the process.

Note: On Windows it is especially important to clear the buffers every so often as otherwise the process will get stuck. See https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Process.html